# Is it possible to raise a parsley error on demand?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parsley.js

My app is using parsley for validation. No issues on the client side. What I am having an issue with is having parsley invalidate a field based on an AJAX response. I'm trying to validate a SSN. Technically, all 9's is a valid format for an SSN, but once it hits the server, our systems see it as invalid. I know I could write a Parsley rule that checks for this, but any field on our form could be invalidated based on rules on the server (I don't have access to these). I'm looking for a way to do something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     if ($(this).parsley().isValid()) {
        $.post("/foo/bar/post",
               $(this).serializeArray(),
                function(response) {
                    if (response.valid) {
                          alert('success!')
                        } else {
                            // this is where I'm lost
                            forceParsleyInvalidation(response.item, response.message)
                        }
                },
                'json');
            }}
```

The response is coming back with all in the info I need, I'm just not sure how to make Parsley do its thing based on what was returned as invalid from the server. I'm trying avoid having to write specific rules for each element that might get invalided.

Comment: From what I understand, you are trying to remove a parsley error, is this correct ?

Comment: More like adding one or triggering an existing error. In this particular case,  if the user entered a partial SSN, a "Enter Valid SSN" message would appear. I need that same message to appear based on the AJAX response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parley allows you to add, update and remove errors via Javascript ([check the documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-ui-for-javascript)).

The following code works but you might need to tweak it based on what you get from the server. For demonstration purposes, I'm setting the `response` values manually and I don't have the `$.post`.

```
if ($(this).parsley().isValid()) {
    var response = [];
    response.item = 'ssn';
    response.message = 'Well, you need to correct this field';

    var FieldInstance = $('[name=' + response.item + ']').parsley(),
        errorName = response.item + '-custom';

    /**
     * You'll probably need to remove the error first, so the error
     * doesn't show multiple times
     */
    window.ParsleyUI.removeError(FieldInstance, errorName);

    // now display the error
    window.ParsleyUI.addError(FieldInstance, errorName, response.message);
}
```

Take a look [**at this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/892jze70/) to see how it works.

Comment: This works great. I was kinda on the right path. Just missing the field instance. Appreciate the help.